# How to perform Order by clause before Group By clause executes?

Tags: mysql

I am having following query, but I want the attachments first order by descending and then Group by url.

```
SELECT _id FROM Attachments GROUP BY url
```

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Order by always comes after group by. For more clarity add the table with some sample data and the expected result into to the question.

Comment: Yes you are right, but how to perform `order by date desc` and then `group by url`

Comment: As pointed out by Abhik, `order by` always comes after `group by`, besides that I don't understand why you are under the impression it would make a difference (result-wise) to do it the other way around? While `GROUP BY url` will merge rows depending on their url, `ORDER BY date DESC` will then bring them in the desired order. The result would be the same even if this was possible (without sub-selects), but it would be more time consuming, because rows that would get merged by the grouping would have been torn apart by your ordering before that.

Comment: @vishalk thats the reason I asked to provide some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I think simply you can do it like this

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT _id,url FROM Attachments ORDER BY date desc) AS a GROUP BY url
```